# PROCEDIMIENTOS ALMACENADOS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mysqli

Hola queridos compañeros , tengo una duda la cual no puedo solucionar y necesito de su ayuda porque tengo un examen dentro de unas horas y estoy practicando.

Estoy estudiando procedimientos almacenados en sql server y tengo esta pregunta;

**Crear un procedimiento almacenado para poder registrar un cliente enviando los siguientes parámetros nombres, cédula, fecha de nacimiento, género. El id del cliente se debe generar dentro del procedimiento.**

Como podría generar el id cliente dentro del procedimiento almacenado?
Tengo realizado el siguiente código hasta el momento.

````
```CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.INS
@NOMBRES VARCHAR(50),@CEDULA VARCHAR(10),
@FECHA_NAC DATE,@GENERO BIT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CLIENTE(NOMBRES,CEDULA,FECHA_NAC,GENERO)
SELECT @NOMBRES,@CEDULA,@FECHA_NAC,@GENERO 
END```
````

Cualquier consejo , ayuda , mejora o critica constructiva se agradece.

````
```Tabla Cliente
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
   IDCLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   NOMBRES VARCHAR(100),
   CEDULA VARCHAR(100) ,
   FECHA_NAC DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   GENERO INT DEFAULT 1,
)```
````

Comment: El campo id es varchar, int ? , danos un ejemplo de un id para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Si amigo es int la tabla es;                                                            
  CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
   IDCLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   NOMBRES VARCHAR(100),
   CEDULA VARCHAR(100) ,
   FECHA_NAC DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   GENERO INT DEFAULT 1,
)

Comment: vas a tener problemas a la hora de insertar un id debido a que el campo es IDENTITY, vas a tener que apagar y prenderlo.

Comment: UY , y en ese caso como seria lo que tendría que hacer?

Comment: No es una buena manera apagar un Identity para insertar y luego volverlo a activar. Entonces para que se crea. Existen dos funciones @@identity y @@Scope_Identity que recogen el último id insertado. Son super similares, pero diferentes. Para el ejemplo que solicitas las dos te devolverán lo mismo. Pero en la documentación oficial, verás que hay un matiz del contexto donde se utiliza. Es importante el matiz por ejemplo cuando se anidan procedimientos almacenados, donde insertas en un maestro, y luego en un detalle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion [Scope_Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), que te devolverá el último id insertado en la conexión y contexto en el que estás.

Al ejemplo que muestras.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE
(
   IDCLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   NOMBRES VARCHAR(100),
   CEDULA VARCHAR(100) ,
   FECHA_NAC DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   GENERO INT DEFAULT 1,
)
```

En el procedure (La sintaxis create or alter no es válida sino tienes un Sql Server 2016), el insert, se realiza no con Select sino con Values, porque solo quieres una fila en función de los datos de los parámetros.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.INS
(
@nombres varchar(100), 
@cedula varchar(100), 
@fecha_nac date,
@genero bit 
)
As
Begin
    DECLARE @NUEVOID int;
    INSERT INTO CLIENTE(NOMBRES,CEDULA,FECHA_NAC,GENERO)
    VALUES (@nombres, @cedula, @fecha_nac, @genero)

    Set @NUEVOID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    SELECT @NUEVOID;

End
GO
```

Ahora una ejecución del procedure.

```
Declare @fecha date = Getdate() ;
EXEC dbo.Ins 
        'Ana',
        '1234',
        @fecha,
        0;
```

[image: Result]

La salida del procedure se ha efectuado con una Select, pero este no es el único modo, te diría que ni tan siquiera el más adecuado, para el ejemplo, ya que se podría haber alimentado un parámetro de tipo Output, y podríamos haber seteado el valor del mismo y a la salida lo tendríamos.

Pero como te indican los parámetros, y no mencionan ningúno de tipo Output.
[Devolución de parámetros](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16)

Una mejora adicional usando Output.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.INS_WITH_OUTPUT
(
@nombres varchar(100), 
@cedula varchar(100), 
@fecha_nac date,
@genero bit,
@NuevoId int OUTPUT
)
As
Begin
    INSERT INTO CLIENTE(NOMBRES,CEDULA,FECHA_NAC,GENERO)
    VALUES (@nombres, @cedula, @fecha_nac, @genero)

    Set @NUEVOID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

End
```

Fíjate que el código ha cambiado minimamente. Hay un parámetro más de tipo int y declarado como ´output´. Y ya no hay un retorno desde una `Select`.

Luego la ejecución:

```
DECLARE @nombres varchar(100)='Lucas';
DECLARE @cedula varchar(100)='321456';
DECLARE @fecha_nac date= Getdate();
DECLARE @genero bit=1;
DECLARE @NuevoId int;

exec dbo.INS_WITH_OUTPUT
    @nombres,
    @cedula,
    @fecha_nac,
    @genero,
    @NuevoId output;

Select @NuevoId;
```

[image: ResultOutput]

Como ves en `@nuevoId` tenemos el valor.

[image: ResultTable]

Si lo llamas desde otro lenguaje, ya no tienes un método tipo `sqlClient.ExecuteScalar/sqlClient.ExecuteReader` sino un `sqlClient.ExecuteNonQuery`;

Comment: Hola javi! un gusto saludarte. Muchas gracias por tu explicación aprendí cosas que no sabia. Pero Si me han dicho que esa manera no es la adecuada de hacerla. Como seria la manera correcta de hacer ese procedimiento? comenzando desde 0 todo. Espero tu respuesta javi la verdad me interesa aprender bien todo esto y como debe de ser para así no perder el ritmo en la U. :)

Comment: No es adecuado apagar un identity. Te he añadido además otra manera de retornar la salida. Para el procedimiento en cuestión, creo que más adecuada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios y ayuda javi. Me ha ayudado muchísimo Saludos desde Ecuador. psdt He formulado otra pregunta por si te interesa :D https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/549612/crear-un-procedimiento-para-crear-editar-o-eliminar-continua

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo la solucion con el identity

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.INS
@NOMBRES VARCHAR(50),@CEDULA VARCHAR(10),
@FECHA_NAC DATE,@GENERO BIT
AS
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT CLIENTE ON
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @IDTEMP INT=(SELECT TOP 1 idcliente FROM CLIENTE ORDER BY 1 DESC)
    IF(@IDTEMP is null)
        SET @ID=1
    ELSE
        SET @ID = @IDTEMP + 1

INSERT INTO CLIENTE(IDCLIENTE,NOMBRES,CEDULA,FECHA_NAC,GENERO)
VALUES (@ID, @NOMBRES,@CEDULA,@FECHA_NAC,@GENERO) 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT CLIENTE OFF
END
```