# Crear un procedimiento para crear, editar o eliminar......Continua

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy practicando SQL Server y el objetivo de esta pregunta es que me puedan retro alimentar con sus conocimientos de un ejercicio que estoy resolviendo.
¿Qué creen que debería de mejorar del código?, ¿Qué errores tengo?, ¿Ustedes piensan que hay otra forma mejor o una mejora que pueda hacerle?. Cualquier comentario es de ayuda :D.

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

> Crear un procedimiento para crear, editar o eliminar una categoría en el mismo procedimiento. El id de la categoría se debe generar dentro del procedimiento si la acción es crear.

##### Tabla Categoría

```sql
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA
(
    IDCATEGORIA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(100)
)
```

##### PROCEDIMIENTO QUE REALICE

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.CON2
@ID INT OUTPUT,
@NOMBRE VARCHAR (100),
@SELECCION INT,
@MENSAJE VARCHAR (100)OUTPUT

AS
    BEGIN
        IF @SELECCION = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @MENSAJE = 'Usted ha seleccionado "Insertar":'
                INSERT INTO CATEGORIA (NOMBRE) 
                VALUES (@NOMBRE)
                SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            END

        IF @SELECCION = 2
            BEGIN
                SET @MENSAJE = 'Usted ha seleccionado "Editar":'
                UPDATE CATEGORIA SET NOMBRE = @NOMBRE WHERE IDCATEGORIA = @ID
            END
        IF @SELECCION = 3
            BEGIN
                SET @MENSAJE = 'Usted ha seleccionado "Eliminar":'
                DELETE FROM CATEGORIA WHERE IDCATEGORIA = @ID
            END

        END 
        GO

-- INSERTAR --

SELECT * FROM CATEGORIA

DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @NOMBRE VARCHAR(100) = 'EL PEPE'
DECLARE @SELECCION INT = 1
DECLARE @MENSAJE VARCHAR (100) 

DECLARE @MEN VARCHAR (100) 
EXEC DBO.CON2
@ID,
@NOMBRE,
@SELECCION,
@MENSAJE=@MEN OUTPUT
PRINT @MEN

-- ACTUALIZAR --

SELECT * FROM CATEGORIA

DECLARE @MEN VARCHAR (100) 
EXEC DBO.CON2 14,'PEPUDO',2,@MENSAJE = @MEN OUTPUT
PRINT @MEN

-- ELIMINAR --

SELECT * FROM CATEGORIA

DECLARE @MEN VARCHAR (100) 
EXEC DBO.CON2 15,'',3,@MENSAJE = @MEN OUTPUT
PRINT @MEN
```

Creo que puede existir una manera que no sea tan extensa... ¿Ustedes qué opinan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el objetivo de la pregunta al menos en la parte de la extensión, es equivocado. No veo porque tener dos lineas o cuatro va a hacer mejor un procedimiento almacenado, mas robusto o eficaz. O al menos no de esta complejidad. Si hablaramos de 8000 lineas versus 16000 pues quizá la cosa cambia, pero entre tener 15, y que genere un plan de ejecución o 12 no va a ser ni mejor ni peor.

Es cierto que el código cuanto más conciso, claro y mantenible, mejor.

Entrando en harina.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.CON2
@ID INT OUTPUT,
@NOMBRE VARCHAR (100),
@SELECCION INT,
@MENSAJE VARCHAR (100)OUTPUT

AS
    BEGIN
        IF @SELECCION = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @MENSAJE = 'Usted ha seleccionado "Insertar":'
                INSERT INTO CATEGORIA (NOMBRE) 
                VALUES (@NOMBRE)
                SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            END

        ELSE IF @SELECCION = 2
            BEGIN
                SET @MENSAJE = 'Usted ha seleccionado "Editar":'
                UPDATE CATEGORIA SET NOMBRE = @NOMBRE WHERE IDCATEGORIA = @ID
            END
        ELSE IF @SELECCION = 3
            BEGIN
                SET @MENSAJE = 'Usted ha seleccionado "Eliminar":'
                DELETE FROM CATEGORIA WHERE IDCATEGORIA = @ID
            END

END 
GO
```

Algo muy simple. Podemos evaluar 1 condición, y sino otra y sino otra, pero no evaluamos 3 condiciones.

Otra perspectiva diferente.

**Merge**

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE DBO.CON3
@ID INT OUTPUT,
@NOMBRE VARCHAR (100),
@SELECCION INT,
@MENSAJE VARCHAR (100)OUTPUT

AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @TABLEMERGE TABLE
    (ACCION NVARCHAR(100), 
    ID     INT, 
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(100)
    );

    Merge dbo.Categoria
    As Target
    Using (
        Select @id, @nombre 
        ) as Source (IDCATEGORIA, NOMBRE)
    On (Target.IDCATEGORIA = source.IDCATEGORIA)
    When Matched and @seleccion =2 Then
        Update
            Set NOMBRE= source.NOMBRE
    When Not Matched  by Target and @seleccion =1 Then
        Insert
            (NOMBRE)
        Values
            (Source.NOMBRE)
    When Matched and @seleccion =3 Then
        Delete
    OUTPUT $ACTION AS MERGEACTION,
       CASE
           WHEN $ACTION = 'DELETE'
           THEN DELETED.IDCATEGORIA
           ELSE INSERTED.IDCATEGORIA
       END,
       CASE
           WHEN $ACTION = 'DELETE'
           THEN DELETED.NOMBRE
           ELSE INSERTED.NOMBRE
       END
       INTO @TABLEMERGE;

       SET @MENSAJE = (SELECT Top(1) Concat('Usted ha seleccionado ',T.ACCION,' para el nombre: ',t.NOMBRE) FROM @TABLEMERGE T)
END ;
```

La sentencia Merge nos permite en la misma instrucción hacer las 3 cosas.
Se basa en una fuente de datos. En el caso la sentencia `Select @id, @nombre` que son los parámetros que le hemos pasado. Un destino a aplicar. (dbo.Categoria) As target
Y luego 3 posibles condiciones.
Que lo encuentre y sea el parámetro Selección = Update, Que lo encuentre y sea el parámetro Selección = Delete. Que no lo encuentre y sea el parámetro selección = Insert

Es un camino posible más.

[Merge](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/merge-upsert-insertar-o-actualizar-en-una-sola-sentencia/) tiene amigos y detractores, pero es una propuesta muy interesante. Sobre todo como es el caso, por aprender algo diferente. Además en la salida, realmente puedes tener toda la información a devolver. Lo que había, y lo que hay.
Las pseudotablas inserted o deleted te pueden ayudar mucho.

Comment: Wow, es un un poco mas complicado. Gracias javi! Pero en este caso como hago para ejecutarlo? Es primera vez que veo el merge. ya estoy investigando!

Comment: Exactamente igual que lo hacías antes.

Comment: Hola javi.  tengo una ultima pregunta. Cual es la función del DECLARE @TABLEMERGE y porque esta dentro del Begin? y también el  OUTPUT $ACTION AS MERGEACTION no lo entiendo del todo. Son las ultimas cosillas que me falta por comprender. Saludos!

Comment: Si te has fijado al ejecutar el procedure, la salida, te devuelve información del registro insertado. No solo el texto que habías puesto, sino el name del usuario borrado. modificado o insertado. Output sirve para recoger la salida de una sentencia. Pero la salida de una sentencia es un conjunto de filas (aunque sea una sola), y eso lo meto en @TABLEMERGE que es una variable tipo Tabla.

Comment: $Action es una columna de la acción que ha realizado la sentencia merge. nvarchar(10) que devuelve `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`